# Jprofile "direct calls to methods of filtered classes" What's it mean?

Tags: jprofiler

I used CPU View to check the performace. 
can someone suggest what does head 'direct calls to methods of filtered classes' signify?
I cannot upload screenshot.

it just like this:
"91.5% -60,324ms -14inv.direct calls to methods of filtered classes"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This node contains threads that only make calls into unprofiled classes - starting from the top level `run()` method of a thread.

To see all method calls, switch to "Sampling" in the profiling settings and deactivate all filters.

[image]

Comment: Kegel，Thank you for your answer. I have disabled all fillters for sampling ,and start Jprofiler again, but it also display "91.5% -6,324ms -14inv.direct calls to methods of filtered classes" on the first note. any suggestions?

Comment: You have not switched to sampling. In sampling it would not display "14 inv.", because sampling cannot record invocation counts.